# Lose the last 3 chars from string variable

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

if the last 4 chars in my string(result) are " AND" or the last three chars are " OR" I would like to remove these from the string. So far I have am trying result.trimend and a few other methods but am unsure how to get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim yourString as string = "sfsdsfd OR "

yourString = CleanString(yourString)



Function CleanString(byval theString as String) as String
    'clean the last spaces
    theString = theString.TrimEnd()

    If theString .EndsWith("OR")) Then
        theString = theString .Substring(0, yourString.Length - 2)
    Else if yourString.EndsWith("AND")) Then
        theString = theString .Substring(0, yourString.Length - 3)
    End If

    Return theString
End Function
```

Comment: Be aware of handling the blanks properly. In your sample nothing will be removed. It might also be a good idea to make the check case-insensitive and to check for " OR" instead of "OR".

Comment: Oh **** I forgot to do TrimEnd()!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use regex:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("\s$|\s?and\s?|\s?or\s?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim mystring As String = "asdfasd AND "
mystring = regex.Replace(mystring, "")
```